# C++ - Define Copy Constructor in Template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a beginner in template coding, and having trouble defining constructor in template, and just looked for answers about that but cannot find related questions.

Basically the class/struct `xpair` is similar to `pair` which has `first` and `second`.

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
struct xpair {
   First first{};
   Second second{};

   xpair(){}
   xpair (const First& first, const Second& second):
              first(first), second(second) {}

   xpair& operator() (const First& first_, const Second& second_) {
      return new xpair (first_, second_);
   }

   xpair& operator= (const xpair& that) {
      return new xpair (that.first, that.second);
   }
};
```

When I'm trying to write something like

```
xpair<string, string> a, b;
a = b;
```

It gives error as

```
non-const lvalue reference to type
'xpair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >'
cannot bind to a temporary of type 'xpair<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
std::__1::basic_string<char> > *'
```

I tried rewrite

```
return new xpair (that.first, that.second);
```

to

```
return new pair (const_cast<First&>(that.first), const_cast<First&>(that.second));
```

But it doesn't work. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `new`. This isn't Java!

In C++, `new` is the keyword for dynamic allocation (evaluating to a pointer), which you're not using.

You'll also have to rethink your return-by-reference semantics as you'll be returning a reference to a local variable. That makes a *dangling* reference.

In fact your semantics look bizarre to me overall. For example, why does `operator=` not actually modify the object being assigned to? You should assign from `that` to `*this`'s members then return a reference to `*this` (or, at least, return `void`).

And I can't tell what your `operator()` is supposed to do — should that be a constructor instead? Hmm, no, you already have one of those… :(

I strongly recommend taking a look at some examples of operator overloading to gain a better understanding not only of C++'s constructs and constraints, but also our idioms and preferred semantics.